# How to hide soft keyboard when click on form field loaded in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview with some form field.
I want to hide the soft keyboard when some of this field are clicked/touched.

(They have already implemented method to interact with user and i can't modify the web page)

I try different solution but nothing works. Below the last solution i tried.

```
 @JavascriptInterface
 public void notEdit(){
     imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     if (imm.isActive(webView)) {
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(),0);
     }
```

This is called when user click on form field thanks to javascript code in web page.

Any help will appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the code passing the if condition ? Check that if you havent

Comment: Yes, it actually pass the if condition and in debugging go on the hideSoftInput method, but doesn't work. It still show the soft keybooard.